# Deleting data in table (SQLite) through java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, database, eclipse, sqlite

as the title suggests, ive been trying to delete data in a table in my SQLite through the use of a button. I have been able to make it work on another class, but i cant seem to make it work on this specific class which i will show you.

the button is called btnDelete, and the method that loads the database and deletes it is called delete_account.

```
    Button btnDelete = new JButton("Delete Account");
    btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            delete_account();
        }
    });

    public void delete_account(){
           try { //start or try
               //1)create a connection variable
               Connection con;
               //2)create an instance of the database class
               Database db=new Database();
               //3)pass the connection from DB to con
               con=db.open_connection();
               //4)create a statement variable to prepare the SQL
               Statement statement=con.createStatement();
               //5)create a query to insert the records
               String query="DELETE FROM tblUsers WHERE userID="+ userid +"";
               //6) execute the SQL code
               if(statement.executeUpdate(query)==1) { //query was successful
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account successfully deleted!");
                   //clear the inputs
                  new MainInterface(user);
                   frmAccountSett.dispose();

               }
           }//end of try
           catch (Exception e){//start of catch
               //display the error
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
           }//end of catch
        }//end of save_recipe()
```

Here's the whole code in the class just in case it is needed:

```
    import java.awt.EventQueue;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
    import javax.swing.JButton;

    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.sql.*;


    public class AccSettings {

private JFrame frmAccountSett;
private JTextField txtFullname;
private JTextField txtUsername;
private JPasswordField txtPassword;
private int userid;
private String user;



/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public AccSettings(String username) {

    user=username;
    //userid = id;
    initialize();
    edit_account();

}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmAccountSett = new JFrame();
    frmAccountSett.setTitle("Account Settings");
    frmAccountSett.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frmAccountSett.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmAccountSett.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Edit Username:");
    lblUsername.setBounds(85, 62, 103, 14);
    frmAccountSett.getContentPane().add(lblUsername);

    txtUsername = new JTextField();
    txtUsername.setBounds(229, 59, 137, 20);
    frmAccountSett.getContentPane().add(txtUsername);
    txtUsername.setColumns(10);

    txtPassword = new JPasswordField();
    txtPassword.setBounds(229, 90, 137, 20);
    frmAccountSett.getContentPane().add(txtPassword);

    JButton btnConfirm = new JButton("Confirm Changes");
    btnConfirm.setBounds(146, 164, 137, 29);
    frmAccountSett.getContentPane().add(btnConfirm);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Edit Password:");
    lblPassword.setBounds(85, 93, 103, 14);
    frmAccountSett.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);
    frmAccountSett.setVisible(true);


    JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete Account");
    btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            delete_account();
        }
    });

    btnDelete.setBounds(299, 227, 125, 23);
    frmAccountSett.getContentPane().add(btnDelete);

    JButton btnBack = new JButton("<< Back");
    btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            frmAccountSett.dispose();
        }
    });
    btnBack.setBounds(10, 227, 103, 23);
    frmAccountSett.getContentPane().add(btnBack);

    JLabel lblFullname = new JLabel("Edit Fullname:");
    lblFullname.setBounds(85, 31, 103, 14);
    frmAccountSett.getContentPane().add(lblFullname);

    txtFullname = new JTextField();
    txtFullname.setColumns(10);
    txtFullname.setBounds(229, 28, 137, 20);
    frmAccountSett.getContentPane().add(txtFullname);

    btnConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            update_account();
        }
    });

}

    public void delete_account(){
           try { //start or try
               //1)create a connection variable
               Connection con;
               //2)create an instance of the database class
               Database db=new Database();
               //3)pass the connection from DB to con
               con=db.open_connection();
               //4)create a statement variable to prepare the SQL
               Statement statement=con.createStatement();
               //5)create a query to insert the records
               String query="DELETE FROM tblUsers WHERE userID="+ userid +"";
               //6) execute the SQL code
               if(statement.executeUpdate(query)==1) { //query was successful
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account successfully deleted!");
                   //clear the inputs
                  new MainInterface(user);
                   frmAccountSett.dispose();

               }
           }//end of try
           catch (Exception e){//start of catch
               //display the error
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
           }//end of catch
        }//end of save_recipe()

    public void update_account(){
           try { //start or try
               //1)create a connection variable
               Connection con;
               //2)create an instance of the database class
               Database db=new Database();
               //3)pass the connection from DB to con
               con=db.open_connection();
               //4)create a statement variable to prepare the SQL
               Statement statement=con.createStatement();
               //5)create a query to insert the records
               @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            String query="UPDATE tblUsers SET fullname='" + txtFullname.getText()+"',"
                    + "username='" + txtUsername.getText()+"',"
                    + "password='" + txtPassword.getText()+"'"
                    + "WHERE userID="+ userid +"";
               //6) execute the SQL code
               if(statement.executeUpdate(query)==1) { //query was successful
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reference successfully updated!");
                   //clear the inputs
                   new MainInterface(user);
                   frmAccountSett.dispose();

               }
           }//end of try
           catch (Exception e){//start of catch
               //display the error
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
           }//end of catch
        }//end of save_recipe()

    //load the results
        public void edit_account()
        {
            try {
                Connection con; //create a variable for con
                Database db = new Database(); //create an instance of database class
                con = db.open_connection(); //set con as connection form database class
                Statement st;
                st = con.createStatement();




              //create a statement variable
              //create the query that will search the table based on similar terms
              String query = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE userID=" + userid+ "";
             //get the resultset of the query (rows)
              ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
              if (rs.next())
              {


                do{
                txtFullname.setText(rs.getString(2));
                txtUsername.setText(rs.getString(3));
                txtPassword.setText(rs.getString(4));

                }
                while(rs.next());

              }
              /*
              else {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Edit failed");
              }
              */
            }
              catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
    }
```

I believe the problem stems mostly from userID which zephyr has stated. I followed a code from another class(frmEditRef), but that class uses a JScrollPane, which when called from another class (frmMainInterface) looks like this:

```
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      int x = table.getSelectedRow(); //get the current row
                        int ans = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to edit this record?");

                        if (ans == 0) {
                            //proceed to edit the transaction
                            //get the id
                            String id = String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(x, 0));
                        new EditRef(user,Integer.valueOf(id));
                        frmUserRef.dispose();

                        }
                }
            });
```

The class im trying to work with does not use JScrollPane. Therefore the coding to it would be different. Here's how it looks like from frmMainInterface:

```
    btnAccountSett.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String id = ;
            new AccSettings(user,Integer.valueOf(id));
        }
    });
```

As you can see, i have no idea what to put in after the "String id =".

I hope this explanation can get through you guys. I myself am having difficulty trying to explain something i dont even fully understand.

Comment: Simply saying something "does not work" and then providing all your code is not helpful for us at all. Please review the [ask] article and [edit] your question accordingly. You need to point out the exact error or problem you're facing.

Comment: my bad... I meant every sense of the word. Specifically though, when i click the button (btnDelete) in the program, nothing is happening. Its not updating, its not giving any errors etc. I clicked it and thats all there is to it.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Is `deleteAccount() ` ever called? Is `userId` correct when adding it to the SQL statement?

Comment: @Zephyr I have not done debugging, I am also very unfamiliar with that word (I only know the basics to programming). The lecturer that taught me wasn't very good at teaching but lets not get into that here. 'deleteAccount()' is called when i click the button. and userID... let me edit my original post and i'll explain it there in a minute.

Comment: Start by printing out some values as your program runs. For example, try printing out userId just before your SQL statement to make sure it is what you expect.